# function to move zeros from a given list to the last

Tags: python, list, function, loops, conditional-statements

```
def move_zero(lst):
    """
    Given a list of integers, moves all non-zero numbers to the beginning of the list and
    moves all zeros to the end of the list.  This function returns nothing and changes the given list itself.

    For example:
    - After calling move_zero([0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4]), the given list should be [1,2,3,4,0,0,0,0] and the function returns nothing
    - After calling move_zero([0,1,2,0,1]), the given list should be [1,2,1,0,0] and the function returns nothing
    - After calling move_zero([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]), the given list should be [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] and the function returns nothing
    - After calling move_zero([]), the given list should be [] and the function returns nothing
    """
    c = 0
    for i in range (0,len(lst),1):
        if (lst[i] == 0):
            lst.pop(i)
            c += 1
    for i in range(0,c):
        lst.append(0)
```

Comment: I'm not seeing a question here.

Comment: when I run it it always give me an error that says list index is out of range

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: This is your 2nd question in an hour which looks like a coding test/homework!

Answer (score 2):

This will make it easier for you to understand and others to read:

Basicly collecting all the nums and the zeros and just adding the lists.

```
def move_zero(lst):
    zeros = []
    nums = []
    for num in lst:
        if num == 0:
            zeros.append(num)
        else:
            nums.append(num)

    return nums + zeros

print(move_zero([1, 2, 4, 0, 4, 0, 4, 6, 0, 1]))
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Nice, uncomplicated approach.  Some of the other answers are over-complicating the task.

Comment: also consider instead of returning the sum of the 2 lists, which creates a new list can be optimized by returning the `nums`, after extending nums with `nums.extend(zeros)`

Comment: I was going to do something like this, but the 'question' seems to require that the `lst` parameter should be mutated and the function return nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
def move_zero(lst):
    zeros = []  # a list to store all the zeros
    for num in lst:
        if num == 0:
            zeros.append(0)
            lst.remove(0)  # remove this zero from the list for now
    lst = lst + zeros  # append the zeros to the end of the list
    return lst
print(move_zero([1, 2, 4, 0, 4, 0, 4, 6, 0, 1]))
```

output: `[1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0]`

Not the most efficient way but it will do the job.
Hope this helps.

Comment: You can optimize this, using `lst.extend(zeros)` instead of `lst = lst + zeros`. This prevents the overhead of the call to the `list.__init__` function, called when the new list is created

Comment: Also, in the comments, it is stated that the function must return `None` and modify the `list` [inplace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm)